# How can I replace in string but exclude some words

Tags: javascript, replace, cpu-word

How can I replace in string but exclude some words from replacing

Ex.:

```
str = "<div>I am a moron</div>";
code = "<div>" + str + "</div>;
newStr = code.replace(str, "I am not a moron");
//newStr = "I am not a moron"
```

I want `//newStr = "<div>I am not a moron</div>"`
Without adding the div tags in the replace method

Comment: `newStr = str.replace("I am a moron", "I am not a moron");`

Comment: BTW, you can always add code from the mobile app by just putting 4 spaces before each line of your code.

Comment: Just did it, thanks :D

Comment: I need the div tags in the replaced string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a regular expression to match the open and close div, so you can put them back with the matching capture groups, `$1`, and `$2`, inside your `replace` call.

Also, if you're not familiar with regular expressions, go check out this [RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/45d5t) where you can play around.

#### Solution

```js
var str = "<div>I am a moron</div>";
var regex = /(<div>)I am a moron(<\/div>)/;

newStr = str.replace(regex, "$1I am not a moron$2");

console.log(newStr);
```

#### Solution 2

This is a more complicated solution, showing how to match several nested elements to get the correct capture groups

```js
var str = '<div class="foo bar2" data-taco="something"><ul><li>I am a moron</li></ul></div>';
var regex = /((?:<.*>)+)I am a moron((?:<\/.*>)+)/;

newStr = str.replace(regex, "$1I am not a moron$2");

console.log(newStr);
```

#### Solution 3

This solution focuses on find replace within the HTML DOM vs a string of html

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.replace(/I am a moron/,"I am not a moron");
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <div id="something" class="foo bar">
      <p>I am a moron</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: And now if I have a string of about 2000 characters, how do I do it?

Comment: A string full of div and li tags, text also

Comment: @Y.Georgiev Can you give an example? Are there line breaks in this string? Other text that needs to remain as well but not replaced?

Comment: @Y.Georgiev Take a look at Solution 2 in my updated answer

Comment: The actual string is str from solution 2 but multiplied by 30, also is there a way of doing that without going through the whole script and then defining a regular expression

Comment: @Y.Georgiev I've added a Solution 3 that demonstrates how to use this on actual HTML, perhaps that can guide you in the right direction.